# How do I set up a gitlab integration in Bluemix DevOps ToolChain?

Tags: ibm-cloud, devops-services

IBM Bluemix DevOps ToolChain allows source code repositories to be only github and IBM version gitlab. My repo is in the public gitlab cloud and i do not intend to move it to IBM's gitlab cloud. How do I set up my Toolchain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** It is now possible to add gitlab.com repositories (or repositories from any other GitLab server on the public internet) to Bluemix DevOps Toolchains.  More details are available in the [Bluemix Documentation](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/ContinuousDelivery/toolchains_integrations.html#gitlab).

**Original (outdated) answer:**
It is not currently possible to add repositories on gitlab.com or other public GitLab servers to an IBM Bluemix DevOps toolchain.  However, that capability is actively under development.

Until that feature is available, you could proceed by duplicating your repository to one of the supported Git providers.  There are instructions for duplicating a repository at https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository/.  In short:

```
git clone --bare https://github.com/exampleuser/old-repository.git
cd old-repository.git
git push --mirror https://github.com/exampleuser/new-repository.git
```

The example uses github.com, but this approach would work for any git repository.

Answer (score 0):

I think this has been added recently, you can just pick it when you add a tool to your toolchain.  There's also a blog post about it https://serifandsemaphore.io/build-a-serverless-api-in-seconds-with-go-c504398d86f6